# Accessing the last value of `\label`

Tags: macros, cross-referencing, environments

I wish to make some editor tools: when I am working only the draft of my document I want to display the 'name' of the `equation` (set by `\label`) after each equation. For example in case of

```
\begin{equation}
\label{eq::einstein}
E=mc^2
\end{equation}
```

I want to see something like

> E=mc^2 (1)
>
> (eq::einstein)

I have to tried to redefine `\label` to store the parameter in `\@currentlabelname` then redefine `environment` `equation` to print `\@currentlabelname` after the `equation` (into a margin note box).

My MnWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{marginnote}
\usepackage{tikz}
\setlength{\marginparwidth}{1.5cm}
\usepackage{todonotes}

\usepackage{regexpatch}
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\@todo}{\setkeys{todonotes}{#1}}{\setkeys{todonotes}{size=\tiny,#1}}{}{}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\note}[2][yellow]{\todo[color=#1]{\tiny #2}}

\makeatletter
\let\oldlabel\label
%%
%% Problem occurs here
%%
\def\label#1{\oldlabel \gdef\@currentlabelname{#1}}

\let\Oldequation\equation
\let\Oldendequation\endequation
\renewenvironment{equation}{\Oldequation}{\Oldendequation \note[blue!90!black]{\textcolor{white}{\@currentlabelname}}}
\makeatother

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{equation}
\label{equ::lenvente}
d_{twin}=\frac{1}{\beta}
\end{equation}

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

Thank you for your time!

Comment: `\usepackage{showkeys}` ?

Answer (score 1):

One obvious mistake in your example is

```
\def\label#1{\oldlabel \gdef\@currentlabelname{#1}}
```

as `\oldlabel` expects an argument (`\let\oldlabel\label`!) and is gobbling up `\gdef`. You could try to

```
\def\label#1{\oldlabel{#1} \gdef\@currentlabelname{#1}}
```

but anyways, what you want is easily achieved by

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{showkeys}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\showkeyslabelformat[1]{\colorbox{blue!90!black}{\textcolor{white}{#1}}}

\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
  \label{equ::lenvente}
  d_{\mathrm{twin}}=\frac{1}{\beta}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image: output]